# My sitemap.xml is empty, how to fix it?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, .htaccess, sitemap

I have a web using Wordpress, everything is good until today. My sitemap file is blank page when open it in browsers (both main sitemap and sub-sitemap). In my Google webmaster, my sitemap is error (empty). I don't know what the happen is going on in my website.

I've using Supper Cache Plugin, but I've removed this plugin. Then, my problem still there.
My XML Sitemap Generator is Google XML Sitemaps Plugin V4.0.7.1

Any idea for this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've deleted php.ini file in my hosting, everything be ok.

Comment: I don't understand how this is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. disable XML map, Save
2. in Permalinks, set Custom %postname%, Save
3. enable XML map, Save.

Apparently worked for plenty of people [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/xml-sitemap-gives-an-empty-page). If it doesn't, there's a few other potential fixes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried your solution, but nothing change after that.

Comment: Have you also tried the (admittedly fairly anecdotal) other suggestions on that link?

Comment: It might be worth making a thread on the WP support forums tbh, since they're going to be more specialised than SO.